# Adding bootstrap glyphicons in the text entity of a-frame

Tags: aframe

Like normal webpage, i wanted to include a glyphicon inside a text entity. For example, in below scene, i have included a text with value "Stop watch" on a plane.

```
<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <a-scene embedded>
<a-plane position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" text="value:Stop watch;align:center;width:5;color:black;"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

Now, like normal webpage, i wanted to replace this text value with a glyph from bootstrap.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`a-text` renders the sets of text from preset font libraries. I'd suggest using the glyphicon as an image.

```
<a-plane material="src: myimage.png"></a-plane>
```

You could use the glyphicons, if you had a font in the necessary [format](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/text.html#fonts), which would have the glyphicons.

Comment: But this will not give same convenience as it gives in 2d world. We won&#39;t be able to add glyph inline with text, am i right?